# Вызов AlertDialog из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio

В классе `public class FragmentMyIngredients extends Fragment` имеется `AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog;`

Который инициализируется в  данном методе

```
private void createDeleteDialog() {
    deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    deleteDialog.setTitle("Вы действительно хотите удалить выбранные ингредиенты?");
    deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            deleteIngredients();
        }
    });
    deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    deleteDialog.setCancelable(true);
    deleteDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        }
    });
}
```

И вызывается при нажатии на пункт меню методом `show()`.

В результате чего возникает ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Что нужно исправить? Я, конечно, понимаю, что в описании ошибки сказано использовать конкретную тему, но попробовав несколько вариантов, к успеху я не пришел.

Comment: От чего наследуется Активити в котором фрагмент?

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko вот полное объявление класса: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Измените строчку:

```
deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getBaseContext());
```

на:

```
deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало. правда, изначально использовал deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());, а уже в ходе экспериментов поменял на то, что написал в вопросе

Comment: getActivity().getApplicationContext() - тоже плохой вариант, getApplicationContext() Вам вообще не нужен, активити предоставит необходимый контекст. Чем выше родителя контекста Вы используете,  тем хуже.

Comment: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/ вот про контекст